# Unable to call AWS-SCT converted stored procedure from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-sct

I have a stored procedure which is converted from SQL Server to PostgreSQL using AWS SCT. Here is the procedure's code which I am unable to call.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.sp_getnthhightesttinyintsp(IN par_nthrow_par numeric, OUT p_refcur refcursor)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    var_NthRow NUMERIC(10, 0) DEFAULT par_NthRow_par;
BEGIN
    OPEN p_refcur FOR
    SELECT
        tinyint_dt
        FROM test.table_1 AS e1
        WHERE var_NthRow - 1 = (SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT tinyint_dt)
            FROM test.table_1 AS e2
            WHERE e2.tinyint_dt > e1.tinyint_dt)
        LIMIT 1;
RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION test.sp_getnthhightesttinyintsp(numeric)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Hi Ali Mohsin, you need to add at least one error code, give to comunity more details, like: programming language, error code, parameters, etc.

Comment: Why are you returning a refcursor? If you want to return a result from a function, use a set-returning function defined as `returns table(...)`  or `returns setof ...`. Those are way easier to deal with than ref-cursors. You are also only returning a single column and single row, so maybe a scalar function that `returns integer` is more appropriate. Unrelated to the question: to return the "n-th highest" value, using a window function is probably a much more efficient way.